# JavaScript onclick functions unbound due to innerHTML usage

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a function in javascript that I intend to use to create/add a link to a 'subLink' div, and add an onclick event to this link that loads associated 'content' to a contentDiv:

```
function addSubLink(text, name, content) {
// append programLink span to subLinks:
    document.getElementById("subLinks").innerHTML += "<span class=\"programLink\" id=\"" + name + "\">" + text + "</span>";
// load program content onclick:
    document.getElementById(name).onclick = function () {
        // set value of programContent to content's value
        document.getElementById("programContent").innerHTML = content;
    }
}
```

This function would be called, for example, by loadAboutPage() to populate the subLink div

```
var whatContent = "<p>A website!</p>";
var whyContent = "<p>Recreation!</p>";
var howContent = "<p>Kludges.</p>";
addSubLink("WHAT", "whatLink", whatContent);
addSubLink("WHY", "whyLink", whyContent);
addSubLink("HOW", "howLink", howContent);
```

The problem is that only the last subLink has an onclick event attached to it (content is loaded and css class changed). That is, it creates WHAT, WHY, and HOW links, but only appends the onclick function to the last called: HOW, in this case.

I'm very rusty when it comes to JavaScript, so I have no idea if it's a result of my lack of knowledge about anonymous functions, or using the local 'name' variable incorrectly, or anything else completely different. I've searched for awhile, but it seems I'm too ignorant to even figure out what a similar problem would be!

Anyway, I greatly appreciate your help! Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here's a complete HTML example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <title>Stack Overflow Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function addSubLink(text, name, content) {
                document.getElementById("subLinks").innerHTML += "<span class=\"programLink\" id=\"" + name + "\">" + text + "</span>";
                document.getElementById(name).onclick = function () {
                    document.getElementById("program").innerHTML = content;
                }
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                var whatContent = "<p>A website!</p>";
                var whyContent = "<p>Recreation!</p>";
                var howContent = "<p>Kludges.</p>";
                addSubLink("WHAT", "whatLink", whatContent);
                addSubLink("WHY", "whyLink", whyContent);
                addSubLink("HOW", "howLink", howContent);
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="programWindow">
                <div id="subLinks"> </div>
                <div id="program"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your HTML and code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is due to:

```
....innerHTML += "...";
```

By setting `innerHTML`, all existing child elements are first removed, then the markup is parsed to create new elements. So, while the *original* "WHAT" and "WHY" spans did have `onclick` bindings, they've being replaced by *similar* elements that don't.

To append a new element *and* keep state, you'll want to use DOM methods like [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement),  [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild), and [`createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode) (or set [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent)/[`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899.aspx)):

```
function addSubLink(text, name, content) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'programLink';
    span.id = name;
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));

// append programLink span to subLinks:
    document.getElementById('subLinks').appendChild(span);

// load program content onclick:
    span.onclick = function () {
        // set value of programContent to content's value
        document.getElementById("programContent").innerHTML = content;
    };
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bG7Dt/